# Access same code with different directory - php

Tags: php, .htaccess, cakephp

I have one website with cakephp that hosted in one folder as below

```
/public_html/mysite.com/demo1
```

I want to access those data from  `"demo1"` to `"demo2"` like if i will run `"/public_html/mysite.com/demo2"` the data should be access from the

> "/public_html/mysite.com/demo1"

I am using `cakephp 2.x`. is there anything that i can make it possible? i know we can do this by htaccess but don't exactly how can i do this becasue route can me grant to access those data from `"demo2"` to `"demo1"`

Comment: why get downvote? can you please justify?

Comment: Possibly check the methods that is occurring, then route accordingly? I am not sure how this is done, but I am sure there are a lot of tutorials because this is a common thing to do. Maybe something similar to this? https://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/using-htaccess-files-for-pretty-urls--net-6049

Comment: What about symbolic link pointing from `demo2` folder to `demo1` folder

Answer (score 3):

You can use the following rule in your /demo2/.htaccess

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /demo1/$1 [L]
```

This will internally forward all requests from /demo2 to /demo1